# ERB replacement with HAML fails in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Greetings!

I've been fooling around with HAML and converted a few view partials from `.erb` to `.haml`. But when i tried to convert `.js.erb` view, it just wont execute. E.g. seems my `.js.haml` is not executed while `.js.erb` works as it should be.

Here's my `.js.erb` (which works as well):

```
<% if @quote.errors.any? && @quote.approved? %>
  $("#data_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form")) %>");
<% else %>
  $("#data_grid").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "quote", :locals => { :quote => @quote }) %>");
  $("#quote_author,#quote_body").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).val("");
  });
<% end %>
```

And here's what i'm replacing it with:

```
-if @quote.errors.any? && @quote.approved?
  $("#data_form").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))}");
-else
  $("#data_grid").prepend("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => "quote", :locals => { :quote => @quote })}");
  $("#quote_author,#quote_body").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).val("");
  });
```

What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean that the javascript isn't executed? Have you checked what is the response that browser gets (check that from Firebug for example).

Comment: This is actually a pretty important question, not sure why some pple elsewhere are saying `.js.haml` is unsupported

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
-if @quote.errors.any? && @quote.approved?
  :plain
    $("#data_form").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))}");
-else
  :plain
    $("#data_grid").prepend("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => "quote", :locals => { :quote => @quote })}");
    $("#quote_author,#quote_body").each(function(i,e) {
      $(this).val("");
    });
```

Comment: @shybovycha : thanks for raising this question.  
@PeterWong :thans for answering :) +1